# Need help checking an ADC0808 / ADC0809 chip in a arcade shooting game

Tags: hardware, arcade

**Main Question:** How can I check a ADC0808 chip to determine if it needs to be replaced or if my issue is something else? Any advice you can offer is SO appreciated!

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
When the arcade is in "Test Mode" (see test mode picture below for context) the output values for the X and Y axis data are not smooth and it only registers a couple of HEX values. Accordingly, it appears that the cursor\crosshair follows the behavior and moves to a different point on the screen when the HEX value changes.

X axis (VRP1X: right to left) - 0080 00C0 00E0 00F0 00F8

Y Axis (VRP1Y: top down) - 0080 00C0 00E0

[image]

[Here is a link to the full schematics](http://arcarc.xmission.com/PDF_Arcade_Manuals_and_Schematics/Operation_Thunderbolt_Schematics.pdf)

**(Overview)**
I am working on a Operation Thunderbolt arcade game. It has two guns (player 1 and 2) that use two 5v potentiometers (2 each gun) to send X and Y signals to a ADC0808 chip which appears to convert the analog signal to digital. The digital value is then used by the game to control the crosshairs of the guns on the screen.

**(Issue)**
The crosshairs are way off in the upper right corner and they are not very responsive and jittery.

**(Troubleshooting)**

- Found the schematics and found where the potentiometer signal is coming into the arcade PCB. I traced the signal to the ADC0808 chip (FYI: the chip on the board is actually a ADC0809N chip). I tested the VCC pin and it was 5v as expected. The input pins 26, 27, 28 and 1 and could see the voltage from the potentiometer within the 5v range.
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
- I put the arcade into test mode and went to the calibration screen. I could see that the X and Y values were responding. Also, while checking voltages (see #1) i noticed that the crosshair was still not behaving correctly, but jumped to an area closer to the middle of the screen
  [image]

Comment: You write that you "could see the voltage from the potentiometer within the 5v range", but did you actually check the full range of each pot? Can you the the voltage from the pot going to the ADC vary through a nice smooth 0-5V range as you adjust the pot?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply brhans! I'll try to get an extra hand and provide additional feedback on the pot voltage while someone else is turning the guns while I monitor the multi-meter. I was having to wedge the gun in place and then take measurements when troubleshooting by myself.

Comment: I did another round of voltage tests on the player 1 gun. The voltage seemed smooth when the guns were moved slowly. ADC0809N's Pin 26 ranged from 1.5 - 3.4 volts for player 1's X axis. Pin 27 ranged from .5 - 4.0 volts for player 1's Y axis.

Comment: @brhans Yes, the voltage was not very erratic when turning the guns. I also added some additional comments about the actual voltages that could be beneficial. Do you think that the change in the crosshairs from the upper right corner to being off center on the screen indicate an issue with the chip? This only occurred when I started testing pins with my multimeter. Thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: "The voltage **seemed** smooth when the guns were moved slowly" - What diagnostic readings did you get for 0.5 - 4.0V? Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: @BruceAbbott No, I don’t have anything like that. I’m extremely new to this.  I was just looking for any odd voltages like gaps, spikes, low voltages... etc. Would a logic probe help? I can get my hands on one of those fairly easy. I just didn’t know of anything in this case where it would be beneficial. Also, thanks for helping!!!

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to disconnect the guns (unplug the harness under the guns) connect a 5k pot directly to the power supply using the +5v out and test the ADC0808 input pins? Would this confirm if the chip was handling the gun input correctly? Could this mess something up on the board?

Comment: Connecting a pot in place of the gun should ensure that the voltage is stable, but you say it is already. The next question is whether the ADC is reading the voltage correctly. The diagnostic numbers should tell you that. Can't help more because you won't tell us what the numbers are.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Sorry, I was not clear on what else I can provide. Would the output on the test screen help? I think it is the hex value that the ADV0808 is sending, but I am not sure and don’t want to mislead anyone that is trying to help me. Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Comment: If it is the raw hex value then yes, it will help. Tell us anyway.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - I think that you are on to something regarding the test mode screen output. The cursor\crosshair jumps to the values below and does not show any values in between. This matches what I see on the screen as well. By that I mean the cursor only moves when the HEX value changes. 
 
**Test Mode Output Values**
X Axis (VRP1X: right to left) - 0080 00C0 00E0 00F0 00F8
Y Axis (VRP1Y: top down) - 0080 00C0 00E0

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. Please put this info in your question.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - I added the additional info to the main question. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: What would the behavior be if the clock chip was bad? Could it look like this issue?

Comment: It looks like someone has scribbled notes on the schematic, mostly in Korean.  But I notice "N/C" on several of the data lines of the ADC0808.  That could explain a few things, couldn't it?

Comment: This is a board from  around 1988/89 according to IC datestamps. The problem might be leaking electrolytic capacitors. The picture shows signs of some sort of cleaning, but impossible to say more. Since the problem looks like missing bits on the databuss, the error might be the ADC or broken connections elsewhere on the board. Following the tracks around with an ohmmeter is probably the only non destructive way to find out.

Comment: I wonder if dust could be the culprit?

Comment: @snips-n-snails If the dust is conductive, it could be the culprit. But trying to troubleshoot a PCB from a partial photo, a partial schematics and no information about how a good board should react in the same situation is not easy...

Comment: First, I would like to thank everyone for their assistance so far. Accordingly, I have added a link to the full schematics in the question if anyone thinks this would be beneficial. Also, I have bought a logic probe and I am seeing some additional items that may be useful.

Comment: I have bought a logic probe and I am seeing some additional items that may be useful. When I used the probe on the ADC0809N (IN0 thru IN3) pins it goes from low to high while turning the gun. I have also seen that the voltage on those pins are ranging between 1V and 4V as the guns are moved and the pot input changes. So, my big question is, how can a know that my input data going to the ADC0809N chip is good. This will allow me to focus on everything upstream and the HEX conversion and the output to the EEPROM.

Comment: I would advise checking continuity between the data bus pins of the ADC and the data bus pins of the CPU.  If the ADC tries to drive correct data onto the bus, but more than half the pins are simply not connected, the CPU won't see that data correctly.

Comment: Chromatix - I just checked all the outputs on bus line (1-5A) from IC 78 (ADC0808) to IC 62 (B67 \ 15 EEPROM). Please let me know if there was something else you thought was worth checking. I'm not too good with schematics. So, you might tell me a specific chip to look into if you see something I missed. Thanks again

Comment: FYI - I have ordered a 28 pin ic socket and a replacement ADC0809N chip. I will try to replace the chip and see where it stands. Please let me know if anyone thinks this is a bad idea.

Comment: UncleBod - The caps (103) appear to be in between the harness and the ADC0809n chip. Can you think of any tip when deciding if they need to be replaced? I have access to a multi-meter and a logic probe at this time.